# How to coloring cells based on the gap in each columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have a data frame like below.

```
A  B  C  D  E
1  1  2  3  -4
a  3  4  5  5
1  2  3  2  9
b  3 4  4  nan
```

I would like to fill each cell with a color based on the difference between column A and another column, when the value in column A is a number.

For example, if the GAP with column A is 10 or more, I want to fill it with blue,
and if the GAP is -10 or less, I want to fill it with red. How should I code it?

Comment: What is the GAP?

Comment: It means the result of subtracting the value of A from each column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/style.html) with a custom function:

```
import numpy as np

def color(df, subset=['B', 'C', 'D'], up=10, low=-10):
    tmp = df[subset].sub(pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce'), axis=0)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.select([tmp.gt(up), tmp.lt(low)],
                                  ['background-color: blue',
                                   'background-color: red'],
                                  None), columns=subset, index=df.index
                       ).reindex_like(df)

df.style.apply(color, axis=None)
```

Output (with a different input):

[image]

Hardcoding the subset and thresholds:

```
def color(df):
    tmp = df[['B', 'C', 'D']].sub(pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce'), axis=0)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.select([tmp.gt(10), tmp.lt(-10)],
                                  ['background-color: blue',
                                   'background-color: red'],
                                  None), columns=subset, index=df.index
                       ).reindex_like(df)
```

Comment: What means of tmp.gt(up), tmp.lt(low)?

Comment: `tmp` is an intermediate dataframe used in the function, `low` is the lower threshold (-10) and `up` the upper threshold (10) used to map the colors. I made them parameters but you could also hardcode the values.

Comment: May I know the code when hardcoded?

Comment: Can I also save the table above to a pre-formatted Excel sheet? Among the cell formats, I want to use the predefined Excel sheet for fonts and lines, and put the result of working in Python only for coloring.

Comment: Maybe, but that's a different question ;)

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your help. I will question separately.